# Band pass filter for Graph

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to do a band pass filter for my graph. Below is my code. The code starting from butter filter is what I added in in attempt to perform band pass filter. However the graph that appears does not seem to differ from my original graph. May I know what am I missing? Is my band pass filter codings correct?

```
from scipy import misc
from scipy import signal
import scipy as sp


for column in df.columns:
    print(df.iloc[:, [1]])
    plt.figure('Train data: Jitter (Local)')
    plt.title('Feature: Jitter (Local)')
    plt.plot(df.iloc[:, [1]])
    plt.show()
    
    def butter_bandpass_filter(data, lowcut, highcut, fs, order=5):
        nyq = 0.5 * fs
        low = lowcut / nyq
        high = highcut / nyq
        b, a = butter(order, [low, high], btype='band', analog=True)
        y = lfilter(b, a, data)
        return y
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two main issues:  1) you're defining the filtering function in your loop, but not calling it.  2) you're designing an analog filter and using it like a digital filter.

1. Add a call to the filtering function, e.g: `output = butter_bandpass_filter(data, lowcut, highcut, fs, order)`.  You'll need to substitute values for all of those parameters. I'll provide a big example after this to demonstrate usage of them.
2. Change analog=True to analog=False.  This way, you'll get the digital filter that lfilter needs to work.  You can also save some lines of code by using the original cutoff frequencies in Hz and adding fs=fs to your butter command.  That's also shown in the example below.  Analog filter design is used when you want to design a filter in the real world, like when using discrete components like resistors, capacitors and inductors.

There's a third issue, which is you should be using SOS coefficients for better numerical stability.  I've included this in my example below so you can play with it and see the effect.  SciPy recommends you always use 'sos'.

Below is a little playground/sandbox code I wrote up for you.  It generates two sinusoids at f1 and f2 Hz, then it generates two bandpass filters.  One of them is meant to extract f1 (and surrounding frequencies) and the other f2 (and surrounding frequencies).  I didn't see example data in your code, so I wasn't sure how your dataframes were set up.

One thing I encourage you to play with is changing sos_mode=True to sos_mode=False (i.e. use the "ba" coefficients).  You'll see in the bandpass filter response for the first filter that it's really getting distorted, due to numerical issues, whereas the second filter is fine.

Enjoy and let me know if you still have questions.  And, yes, you can remove a **lot** of code from the design function I wrote if you don't want to view the filter response and only want to use SOS mode.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np

Fs = 10e3  #Sampling rate of 1kHz
Ts = 1./Fs # Sampling period is inverse of sampling rate

########### Generate Example Input 
#    I'll generate an input x that's composed of two sinusoids
#      at frequencies f1 and f2 that are defined from time=Tstart
#       to time=Tend
Tstart = -25e-3 # time to start
Tend = 125e-3   # time to end
t = np.arange(Tstart,Tend,Ts) # start, stop, step
f1 = 100 # frequency of first sinusoid
f2 = 400
x = np.sin(2 * np.pi * f1 * t) + np.sin(2 * np.pi * f2 * t)

########### Filter Design Function
#     Just design a filter - don't actually filter
def design_butter_bandpass_filter(lowcut, highcut, Fs, order=5, sos_mode=True, view_it=True):
    # The digital filter design that you need for lfilter
    #  the parameter fs=Fs lets us skip the manual Hz -> rad/s conversion
    if sos_mode:
      sos_digital = signal.butter(order, [lowcut, highcut], btype='band', fs=Fs, analog=False, output='sos')
    else:
      b_digital, a_digital = signal.butter(order, [lowcut, highcut], btype='band', fs=Fs, analog=False, output='ba')

    if view_it:
      if sos_mode:
        w, h = signal.sosfreqz(sos_digital, fs=Fs, worN=range(lowcut * 3 // 4,highcut * 5 // 4))
      else:
        w, h = signal.freqz(b_digital, a_digital, fs=Fs, worN=range(lowcut * 3 // 4,highcut * 5 // 4))
      plt.semilogx(w, 20 * np.log10(abs(h)))
      plt.title('Butterworth filter frequency response ' + 'SOS mode' if sos_mode else 'BA mode')
      plt.xlabel('Frequency [radians / second]')
      plt.ylabel('Amplitude [dB]')
      plt.margins(0, 0.1)
      plt.grid(which='both', axis='both')
      plt.axvline(lowcut, color='green') # lower cutoff frequency
      plt.axvline(highcut, color='green') # upper cutoff frequency
      plt.show()

    if sos_mode:
      return sos_digital
    else:
      return (b_digital, a_digital)


########### Filter Design using the Filter Design Function

# Common parameters
filter_order = 5
sos_mode = True

# Design a filter to extract the first sinusoid.  You only need to do this once, unless the cutoffs or order change
lower_cutoff1 = f1 - 50
upper_cutoff1 = f1 + 50
filt1 = design_butter_bandpass_filter(lower_cutoff1, upper_cutoff1, Fs, filter_order, sos_mode)

# Design a filter to extract the second sinusoid.  You only need to do this once, unless the cutoffs or order change
lower_cutoff2 = f2 - 50
upper_cutoff2 = f2 + 50
filt2 = design_butter_bandpass_filter(lower_cutoff2, upper_cutoff2, Fs, filter_order, sos_mode)


########### Signal Filtering

# Filter the signal using your filter coefficients
if sos_mode:
  y1 = signal.sosfilt(filt1, x)
  y2 = signal.sosfilt(filt2, x)
else:
  y1 = signal.lfilter(filt1[0], filt1[1], x)
  y2 = signal.lfilter(filt2[0], filt2[1], x)


########### Plotting

# Plot the data
fig, ax = plt.subplots(3,1);
fig.tight_layout()
ax0 = ax[0]
ax0.set_title(f'Input Signal - sinusoids at {f1} Hz and {f2} Hz')
ax0.plot(t,x)

ax1 = ax[1]
ax1.set_title(f'Filtered Signal - bandpass filtered from {lower_cutoff1} Hz to {upper_cutoff1} Hz')
ax1.plot(t,y1)

ax2 = ax[2]
ax2.set_title(f'Filtered Signal - bandpass filtered from {lower_cutoff2} Hz to {upper_cutoff2} Hz')
ax2.plot(t,y2)
plt.show()
```